# Do I need to use future_map or map to parallelize fable forecast?

Tags: r, forecasting, fable-r, r-future

I've created a tsibble of ~75K time series in R Studio on my local machine.

I'm looking for ways to speed up the processing time before I migrate the process to a VM with more processing power.

Does Fable handle all of the parallel processing in the background or are there more opportunities to make the code more efficient?

Here is an example of my code

```
plan(multisession, gc= TRUE)
tic()
results <- train %>%
  group_by_key() %>%  
  model(my_dcmp_spec) %>% 
  forecast(h="10 weeks") %>% 
  ungroup()
toc()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Currently fable will model each of the series in parallel (`model()`) according to your `plan()`. The forecasts will not yet be done in parallel, but this is planned for an upcoming release: https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/issues/268

Comment: I would need a specification. When model() works in parallel, does it split data, model or both? Assuming we have a tsibble with a key that includes three levels and willing to test modelA and modelB, will the parallelization split into either six, three or two streams?

Comment: Currently it is split into 6, however there is some argument that splitting 3 into 2 would be better (less transfer of data to worker nodes).

Comment: Thanks Mitch. Your support is always extremely valuable

Comment: @MitchellO'Hara-Wild how about the interpolate function? Will that parallelize?

Comment: Not currently, but when implemented it will without changes to your code.